# Add another SO file when developing an SO file

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I am developing a so file called "rowen".

Among the library functions, there is a json related file (Libs/json/json.cpp)

This is a wrapping of some features of "jsoncpp".

**Q1. i have used the jsoncpp related function (write) in the "print" function. but without linking jsoncpp, it does not give any error. why?**

```
// json.hpp
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

namespace Json
{
    inline void print(Json::Value& __param, std::string __title);
}

// json.cpp
namespace Json
{
    void print(Json::Value& __param, std::string __title)
    {
        Json::StyledWriter style_writer;
        std::string output = style_writer.write(__param);
        printf("=========== %s ===========================\n", __title.c_str());
        printf("%s\n", output.c_str());
    }
}
```

And,
here is a portion of the CMakeLists.txt file in the Root path.

It includes the different modules in the Libs folder and bundles the source (.c or .cpp) files together to create the so file.

```
// Root CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Rowen-Libraries)

set(rowenSources )

# set libraries (default)
include(Libs/core/import.cmake)

# set libraries (optional)
OPTION(ENABLE_JSON      "Enable Json Wrapping Library"      ON)

if (ENABLE_JSON)
include(Libs/json/import.cmake)
endif()

# build shared libraries
add_library(rowen SHARED ${rowenSources})


// Libs/json/import.cmake
insert(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/json.hpp) # include to rowenIncludes
insert(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/json.inl) # include to rowenIncludes
insert(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/json.cpp) # include to rowenSources

# Check for pkg-config
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(JSONCPP REQUIRED jsoncpp)
link_libraries(${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})  # ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES} print "jsoncpp"
```

**Q2. Why do I link jsoncpp but not see it through ldd or nm?**

**I want to make it so that libjsoncpp is required to use librowen.**

```
$ ldd librowen.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007fb750f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007fb745a000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000007fb72c6000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000007fb72a2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007fb7149000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007fb74e3000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000007fb7090000)

$ nm -D librowen.so | grep jsoncpp        (print black)
$ objdump -T librowen.so | grep jsoncpp   (print black)
```

- NOTE: On my system, jsoncpp exists in "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.1". It installed fine, and it is used by many other projects on my system.

Comment: "_but without linking jsoncpp, it does not give any error. why?_" what? You did `link_libraries(${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})`... actually I suppose you do have a problem. `link_libraries` only applies to targets defined after it, but your target is defined before it.

Comment: as for why you don't get errors, maybe it's just that your build tooling doesn't report link errors until it comes to linking things to an executable? before you fix you `link_libraries` positioning, try adding an executable that links to you rowen library and see if you get link errors then.

Comment: @user If the librowen.so file is used by another program, a ```jsoncpp``` linking error will occur. In the CMakeLists.txt I added not only json, but also ```core/import.cmake```, where I added link_libraries(```pthread```), so when I checked with ```ldd``` I could see libpthread.so.0 being added, but jsoncpp doesn't work like this, so I think that's the problem.

Comment: does moving `link_libraries` to go before your `add_library` solve the "missing link" issue?

Comment: @user Yes... I tried ```adding link_libraries(jsoncpp)``` or ```target_link_libraries(rowen jsoncpp)``` just before or just after ```add_library(rowen SHARED ${rowenSources})``` in the ```root CMakeLists.txt```, not in ```json/import.cmake```, but both gave the same linking error and libjsoncpp.so was not found in the ```ldd```.

Comment: I recomment providing a cmake configuration file for your library since this makes it much easier to use the lib in a cmake project using the lib. (It does however increase the complexity of your library project a bit.) See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#exporting-targets